# create a column based on dense observations

Tags: r

I have a large dataset "dat" like this:

```
Sub Day 
 1   1
 1   1
 1   1
 1   2
 1   2
 1   14
 1   14
 1   14
 1   15
 1   15
 2   1
 2   1
 2   1
 2   2
 2   2
 2   12
 2   12
 2   12
 2   15
 2   15
 2   16
```

...

I want to create a column "ADDL" based on "Day" so that whenever there are dense observations on "Day"(number of observations for "Day">2, for example, for subject 1, we have 3 observations for day 1, 2 for day 2, 3 for day 14 and 2 for day 15, therefore, day 1 and 14 are dense observations and I want to give ADDL value to their corresponding FIRST observation), ADDL=(maximum "Day" number for that subject) - (corresponding "Day" number), otherwise give ADDL zero. The expected output should look like this:

```
Sub Day  ADDL
 1   1    14
 1   1    0 
 1   1    0
 1   2    0  
 1   2    0
 1   14   1
 1   14   0
 1   14   0
 1   15   0
 1   15   0
 2   1    15
 2   1    0
 2   1    0
 2   2    0
 2   2    0
 2   12   4
 2   12   0
 2   12   0
 2   15   0
 2   15   0
 2   16   0
```

...

It's a little bit complicated situation and I did not manage to realize it, could anyone give some ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense.  Why 14 for the 1,1 case?  And why 0 for the remaining 1,1 cases?  Why 1 for the 1,14 case?  etc.

Comment: ... and why 15 for Sub 2 Day 1? should be 16 according to your description. Same goes for the 2, 12 case.

Comment: Hi Matt and djas, sorry for the confusion. The criteria for dense observations is that as long as there are more than 2 observations for "Day", we count it as dense, and give the FIRST observation ADDL value for that Day number. For instance, for subject 1, we have 3 observations for day 1, 2 for day 2 and 3 for day 14 and 2 for day 15, therefore, day 1 and 14 are dense observations and I want to give ADDL value to their corresponding first observation, and ADDL= (max day number for that subject) - (the corresponding day number for the first observation). The same criteria apply to subject 2.

Comment: The latest information does not help to clarify what you really want.  You seem to assign ADDL of 14 to the first 1,1 observation and 1 to the first 1,14 observation.  Why is this?  And why the ADDL of 4 to the first 2,12 observation?

Comment: Hi Matt, assigning ADDL of 14 to the first 1,1 observation is because the maximum Day for subject 1 is 15, and ADDL= (max day number for that subject) - (the corresponding day number for the first observation), therefore, ADDL=15-1=14. Assigning 1 to the first 1,14 observation is because ADDL=15-14=1. The same criteria applies to the first 2,12 observation: ADDL=16-12=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I could follow exactly, but the following seems to match your output:

```
ff = function(x, dens) {
    tab = table(x)
    vals = as.numeric(names(tab)[tab >= dens])
    inds = match(vals, x)  #'match' for the first observation
    x[inds] = max(x) - x[inds]
    x[!seq_along(x) %in% inds] = 0
    return(x)
}
ave(DF$Day, DF$Sub, FUN = function(x) ff(x, dens = 3))
# [1] 14  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 15  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0
ave(DF$Day, DF$Sub, FUN = function(x) ff(x, dens = 2))
# [1] 14  0  0 13  0  1  0  0  0  0 15  0  0 14  0  4  0  0  1  0  0
```

Where `DF`:

```
DF = structure(list(Sub = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Day = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 16L)), .Names = c("Sub", "Day"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```